# Error in installing the package RcppArmadillo

Tags: r

While installing the package RcppArmadillo, I am getting below error.

```
installing to /usr/lib64/R/library/RcppArmadillo/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) :
  object 'SHLIB.maker' not found
Error : unable to load R code in package ‘RcppArmadillo’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘RcppArmadillo’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/RcppArmadillo’
Warning message:
In install.packages("RcppArmadillo_0.3.920.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL,  :
  installation of package ‘RcppArmadillo_0.3.920.1.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Did you first install package `Rcpp`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add R's repository to your system:

Use your favorite text editor (I'm using gedit as an example) to open `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add this line to the file (if this is slow, use another mirror. You may also want to change precise into the codename for your Ubuntu version --- e.g., trusty for 12.04):

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/
```

This works for me `install.packages('RcppArmadillo')`

```
 > install.packages('RcppArmadillo')
    Installing package into ‘/home/priyankara/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
    (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
    trying URL 'http://mirror.bjtu.edu.cn/cran/src/contrib/RcppArmadillo_0.5.300.4.tar.gz'
    Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 967193 bytes (944 KB)
    ==================================================
    downloaded 944 KB

    * installing *source* package ‘RcppArmadillo’ ...
    ** package ‘RcppArmadillo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
    * checking LAPACK_LIBS: divide-and-conquer complex SVD available via system LAPACK
    ** libs
    g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/priyankara/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
    g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/priyankara/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
    g++ -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG   -I"/home/priyankara/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/Rcpp/include"  -I../inst/include -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
    g++ -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o RcppArmadillo.so RcppArmadillo.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
    installing to /home/priyankara/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RcppArmadillo/libs
    ** R
    ** inst
    ** preparing package for lazy loading
    ** help
    *** installing help indices
    ** building package indices
    ** installing vignettes
    ** testing if installed package can be loaded
    * DONE (RcppArmadillo)
```