# Error in installing the package RcppEigen

Tags: c++, r, gcc

When I tried to install RcppEigen on CentOS, I am getting the following error. Please note that I can only install packages from source. 
I also have the compiler version:

```
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-55)

R CMD INSTALL RcppEigen_0.3.1.2.1.tar.gz
installing to /home/cyrildl/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/RcppEigen/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) :
  object 'SHLIB.maker' not found
Error : unable to load R code in package ‘RcppEigen’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘RcppEigen’
* removing ‘/home/cyrildl/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.3/RcppEigen’
```

Comment: `gcc-4.1.2` from 2008?  Seriously?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31024454/error-in-installing-the-package-rcpparmadillo (or at least the error is addressed here)

Comment: @ChrisStathis: that is not clear. It's a possibly an Rcpp error from using a jurrassic version too.

Comment: @Cyril: I have not seen that eror, ever, I think.  But I have not used that compiler is close to a decade.  For what it is worth: what Rcpp version do you have installed?  We generally recommend `g++-4.6` or newer, preferably `g++-4.8` or newer.

Comment: Also, why RcppEigen version 0.3.1.2.1?  We are now at [version 0.3.2.9.0](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppEigen/index.html) (which may however start to giggle if it sees you come with that compiler...)

Comment: I am trying to install RcppEigen version 0.3.1.2.1 for compatibility issues. I was hoping to be able to install the package with my very old compiler but it looks like it is not possible. Thank you Dirk